# How to get all my github pull requests of my github account using github api

Tags: github-api, pull-request

i want get get all pull requests of all my repos using github api v3.

I have tried the following issue endpoint:
`https://api.github.com/user/issues?filter=all&state=all&sort=create&direction=desc`

This will return all issues including the pull requests. but is there any way of getting just the pull requests (not all issues) using page parameters. I.e. I want to get the first 10 pull requests and then next 10 pull requests using the "page" and "per_page" parameters.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `type:pr` to search only the pull requests. i.e. `https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=type=pr&state=all&sort=create&direction=desc&page=1&per_page=10`

Comment: you may misunderstood my purpose. I want to get all pull request of  repos of my github account.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, what you want are the pull requests initiated by you (I guess that's what you mean by `pull request of repos of my github account`

Please add your username instead of mine (swarajpure) and you'll get your PRs:

> https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=user:swarajpure+type:pr&per_page=10&page=1

This by default will show first 10 PRs. To see next 10 PRs, please enter `page=2` and so on.

For more details: https://swarajpure.medium.com/github-apis-fetching-pull-requests-issues-by-a-user-organisation-repository-84ae934a106b

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are a great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I totally get your point. I've answered the question already. The blog only explains about more examples for different scenarios. Thanks for the heads up!